# Regex for check the input string is just in persian language

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I work with MVC and I am new on it. I want to check input values is only in Persian language (Characters) by `[RegularExpression]` Validation.
 So I think to use Regex and need to check in range of unicodes, but I don't lnow how can find range of Persian characters Unicode. Am I right about this Regex? what is your suggestion and how can I find range of Unicode in Persian

Comment: I don't see why you would need a regex to check whether a character is within a given range.

Comment: Characters != language. For example, 'hdafhladf' is not English. And I'm sure there are some characters that are not officially classified as "Persian" but are allowed in Persian language (maybe whitespace characters?)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Check first letter and last letter range in Persian I think something like this:

```
"^[آ-ی]$"
```

Comment: not work with any Persian chars be like "خ", "پ", ... because this is not in Arabic language! I thinks better is use: [\u0600-\u06FF]

Comment: @NabiK.A.Z.  `آ` codepoint is `0622` and `ی` codepoint is `06CC` and `Arabic Letter Khah` `خ` is `062E`. So it's included in said range. That's right with `پ` too. BTW, why didn't you update your blog for years?

Comment: @revo, You said correct, but the other way, in the `[آ-ی]` you don't allow `ء`, `،`, `؛`, `۰-۹`,... (https://regex101.com/r/rM1TnT/1) but in `[\u0600-\u06FF]` you can use more of the required characters: (https://regex101.com/r/rM1TnT/2) Of course, this depends on the user's needs.
And about my blog, Thanks, I don't have any answer for it! :-D maybe it was talisman !!! ;-)

Comment: @NabiK.A.Z. `[آ-ی]` shouldn't contain numbers if someone use it while thinking about a similar range like `[a-z]` (it means letters only). But `[آ-ی]` contains Arabic numbers too and has much more characters than some Persian user needs. Second range `[\u0600-\u06FF]` also includes superfluous characters and symbols which we can't call it Farsi. I [posted an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50018120/1020526) at current page and with more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50018691/1020526) about this topic you may want to see.

Answer (score 29):

Persian characters are within the range: `[\u0600-\u06FF]`

Try:

```
Regex.IsMatch(value, @"^[\u0600-\u06FF]+$")
```

Comment: `[\u0600-\u06FF\uFB8A\u067E\u0686\u06AF]` is better. see http://stackoverflow.com/a/22565376/896465

Answer (score 15):

```
Regex.IsMatch(Text, @"^([\u0600-\u06FF]+\s?)+$")
```

This Only Contain standard Arabic symbols range But Persian also include 4 More Characters:

```
ژ \uFB8A
پ \u067E
چ \u0686
گ \u06AF
```

So You Should Use:

```
^[\u0600-\u06FF\uFB8A\u067E\u0686\u06AF]+$
```

If you want to match Zero-width-non-joiner you should add this too:

```
\u200C
```

Comment: consider accepting space and Zero-width non-joiner in characters! https://stackoverflow.com/a/34869397/5160077

Comment: Codepoints `0600` through `06FF` include `067E`, `0686` and `06AF` obviously. You don't need to repeat them.

Answer (score 15):

## TL;DR

#### All answers that say use `\u0600-\u06FF` or `[آ-ی]` are simply WRONG.

> #### i.e. `\u0600-\u06FF` contains 209 more characters than you need! and it includes numbers too!

#### Farsi MUST used character sets are as following:

- Use `^[آابپتثجچحخدذرزژسشصضطظعغفقکگلمنوهی]+$` for letters.
- Use `^[۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹]+$` for numbers.
- Use `[ ‬ٌ ‬ًّ ‬َ ‬ِ ‬ُ ‬ْ ‬]` for vowels.

Or a union of those. You may want to add other Arabic letters like Hamza `ء` to your character set additionally.

---

This answer exists to fix a common misconception. Codepoints `0600` through `06FF` do not denote **[Persian / Farsi alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persian_alphabet)** (neither does `[آ-ی]`):

```
[\u0600-\u0605 ؐ-ؚ\u061Cـ ۖ-\u06DD ۟-ۤ ۧ ۨ ۪-ۭ ً-ٕ ٟ ٖ-ٞ ٰ ، ؍ ٫ ٬ ؛ ؞ ؟ ۔ ٭ ٪ ؉ ؊ ؈ ؎ ؏
۞ ۩ ؆ ؇ ؋ ٠۰ ١۱ ٢۲ ٣۳ ٤۴ ٥۵ ٦۶ ٧۷ ٨۸ ٩۹ ءٴ۽ آ أ ٲ ٱ ؤ إ ٳ ئ ا ٵ ٮ ب ٻ پ ڀ
ة-ث ٹ ٺ ټ ٽ ٿ ج ڃ ڄ چ ڿ ڇ ح خ ځ ڂ څ د ذ ڈ-ڐ ۮ ر ز ڑ-ڙ ۯ س ش ښ-ڜ ۺ ص ض ڝ ڞ
ۻ ط ظ ڟ ع غ ڠ ۼ ف ڡ-ڦ ٯ ق ڧ ڨ ك ک-ڴ ػ ؼ ل ڵ-ڸ م۾ ن ں-ڽ ڹ ه ھ ہ-ۃ ۿ ەۀ وۥ ٶ
ۄ-ۇ ٷ ۈ-ۋ ۏ ى يۦ ٸ ی-ێ ې ۑ ؽ-ؿ ؠ ے ۓ \u061D]
```

255 characters are fallen in this range, Farsi alphabet has 32 letters that in addition to Farsi demonstration of digits it would be 42. If we add vowels (Arabic vowels originally, that rarely used in Farsi) and **Tanvin** (`ً`, `ٍِ ‬`, `ٌ ‬`) and **Tashdid** (`ّ ‬`) that are both a subset of Arabic diacritics not Farsi, we'd end with 46 characters. This means:

### `\u0600-\u06FF` contains 209 more characters than you need!

`۷` with codepoint `06F7` is a Farsi representation of number `7` and `٧` with codepoint `0667` is Arabic representation of the same number. `۶` is Farsi representation of number `6` and `٦` is Arabic representation of the same number. And all reside in `0600` through `06FF` codepoints.

> The shapes of the Persian digits four (`۴`), five (`۵`), and six (`۶`) are
>   different from the shapes used in Arabic and the other numbers have
>   different codepoints.

You can see different number of other characters that doesn't exist in Farsi / Persian too and nobody is willing to have them while validating a first name or surname.

`[آ-ی]` includes 117 characters too which is much more than what someone needs for validation. You can see them all using **[Unicode CLDR](https://unicode.org/cldr/utility/list-unicodeset.jsp)**.

Answer (score 9):

I use this RegExp in my program, and it works correctly. hope to help you:

```
 [پچجحخهعغفقثصضشسیبلاتنمکگوئدذرزطظژؤآإأءًٌٍَُِّ\s]+$
```

Comment: The better way is to do the following:
Regex.IsMatch(Text, @"^([\u0600-\u06FF]+\s?)+$")

Answer (score 0):

Persian characters are within the range: [\u0600-\u06FF] + [\s]

Try:

```
Regex.IsMatch(Text, @"^([\u0600-\u06FF]+\s?)+$")
```

This Patern Contains Letter and space Charachters.

Answer (score 0):

I use these two RegExps in my program as some letters might be actually arabic:

```
^[!@#$%^&*(). ۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹۰+-پچجحخهعغفقثصضشسیبلاﺐتنمکگوئدذرزطﺐظژؤآإأءًٌٍَُِّﻢﺷﺠﺪﮑﺬﻋﻮﻂﺶﺰﺣﻣﮕﻒﺤﻻﻄﻟﭼﻫﻼﻗﺒﺗﺨﻪﻬﻓﯾﺼﺟﮔﻇﺑﭽﺌﻞﺖﺿ]+$
```

```
^[ﻢﺷﺠﺪﮑﺬﻋﻮﻂﺶﺰﺣﻣﮕﻒﺤﻻﻄﻟﭼﻫﻼﻗﺒﺗﺨﻪﻬﻓﯾﺼﺟﮔﻇﺑﭽﺌﻞﺖﺿﺎﺄﭙﻈﻏﻦﯿﻔﻤﻨﻐﻌﮏﺻﺧﻃﭘﺳﻘﻧﯽﻖﺸﮐﻠﺴﺮﺘ]+$
```

it might not look very good but it works fine in my code.