# Dedicated Regular Expression for Persian alphabet

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I define a regular expression which solely accept Persian alphabet characters?

I tried the following function, but it doesn't work properly:

```
function Just_persian(str){
  var p=/[پچجحخهعغفقثصضشسیبلاتنمکگوئدذرزطظژؤإأءًٌٍَُِّ\s]+$/;
  if(!str.match(p))
    alert("invalid format");
}
```

Comment: @BhavikKama: I didn't write any thing. it's my question that how can I do it.

Comment: stack-overflow is about finding the solution after you have tried something or googled..have you tried to search anything on that?

Comment: @BhavikKama: yes, very much! but I didn't find my answer. help me please

Comment: @BhavikKama: excuse me, I am beginner in stack-overflow . why my question rated to -2 ????

Comment: because in stackoverflow spoon feeding is not allowed..just ask the question with what is your question what have you tried yet and what are the steps you have taken to achieve the solution of your problem.just edit your question with the above mentioned details.thanks

Comment: @BhavikKama: thank you very much, I didn't know these  details.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Persian characters are within the [Arabic Unicode block](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/arabic/list.htm), which ranges from U+0600 to U+06FF (which is specified in character class as `\u0600-\u06FF`).

```
function just_persian(str){
    var p = /^[\u0600-\u06FF\s]+$/;

    if (!p.test(str)) {
        alert("not format");
    }
}
```

Adapted to JavaScript from this question: [Regex for check the input string is just in persian language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10561590/regex-for-check-the-input-string-is-just-in-persian-language)

Comment: So you solved your problem??

Comment: The answer is utterly wrong. What's up with the `@"..."`? They won't just magically work when you copy from .NET code to JS.

Comment: @nhahtdh gracefully fixed your own question without downvoting or presenting his own answer.  Props to him.

Comment: @nhahtdh am developer of objective c..i just put ma logic. @ was prefix added in string when you writting in Objective c.. and i just give her a logical answer syntax and all should not matter

Comment: @BhavikKama i have try with your code but his alwys getting alert so can you please explain in this funcation is getting automatically translate input value or enter directly persian lang.

Comment: @BhavikKama can you please help me one?

Comment: Please check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50018691/7330316 about Unicode of Persian characters.

Comment: Persian characters are NOT within the Arabic Unicode block. There are letters that don't exist in the Arabic language at all.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [persianRex](http://imanmh.github.io/persianRex/), it detects all Persian characters in different keyboard layouts and it's open source.

Download it and put it in your project folder. Then include it in your HTML like this:

```
<script src="persian-rex/dist/persian-rex.js"></script>
```

Then in your Javascript you can do this:

```
function Just_persian(str){
  if(persianRex.text.test(str))
    alert("not format");
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Persian Characters are within the range: [\u0600-\u06FF] And: [\s]

Use This Code:

```
function Just_persian(str){
  var p=/@"^([\u0600-\u06FF]+\s?)+$"/;
  if(!str.match(p))
    alert("not format");
}
```

This Patern includes Letter and space Charachters.

Comment: it doesn't contain persian special characters : [گ چ پ ژ ]