# Using range in regex for Arabic letters

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

When using Regex in Python, it's easy to use brackets to represent a range of characters `a-z`, but this doesn't seem to be working for other languages, like Arabic:

```
import re
pattern = '[ي-ا]'
p = re.compile(pattern)
```

This results in a long error report that ends with

```
raise error("bad character range")
sre_constants.error: bad character range
```

how can this be fixed?

Comment: The end range character is at code point 1575 (decimal), while the start range is at code point 1610 (decimal), which explains the error you are having.

Comment: BTW: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50018691/8291949) answer how to properly validate Persian/Farsi.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use Unicode escapes instead.

```
>>> re.compile('[\u0627-\u064a]')
<_sre.SRE_Pattern object at 0x237f460>
```

Answer (score 11):

Since Arabic character is rendered from right to left, the **correct** string below, which reads "from `ا` to `ي`" is rendered backward (try to select the string if you want to confirm):

```
'[ا-ي]'
```

Console output:

```
>>> re.compile('[ا-ي]')
<_sre.SRE_Pattern object at 0x6001f0a80>

>>> re.compile('[ا-ي]', re.DEBUG)
in
  range (1575, 1610)
<_sre.SRE_Pattern object at 0x6001f0440>
```

So your pattern `'[ي-ا]'`, is actually "from `ي` to `ا`", which is an invalid range, since the code point of `ا` is smaller than code point of `ي`.

To prevent confusion, Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams's suggestion of using Unicode escape is a good alternative to the solution I provide above.

Comment: While the comment about right-to-left range is correct, the answer is probably misleading for everybody who wants to validate/prase Farsi: Do not use `[ا-ي]` ! See the canonical answer by [revo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1020526/revo) how to [properly validate Persian/Farsi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50018691/8291949).

Comment: A bit more general: `[ءؤئإآأا-ي]+`

Answer (score 2):

The approved answer does work, however the unicode `[\u0627-\u064a]` does not include variations of the letters 'ا' such as 'أ', 'آ' or 'إ', and the letter 'و' with its' variation 'ؤ'. (I wanted to comment/suggest-edit to the approved answer but there's a queue)

So in case someone is (re)visiting this question and needs those letter variations, a unicode that worked better for me was **[\u0600-\u06FF]**, making the answer:

```
pattern = re.compile('[\u0600-\u06FF]')
```

Comment: i think ur the best one