# Django Form validate arabic CharField

Tags: python, regex, django, django-forms

Based on this answer here: [Using range in regex for Arabic letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27685984/using-range-in-regex-for-arabic-letters)

I want to validate a Form field to allow only Arabic characters. My Form is:

```
fullname_arabic = forms.CharField(
    label=_('Arabic Full Name'),
    widget=widgets.TextInput(),
    help_text=_('Please enter your arabic name'),
)
```

The Form has a `clean` method which is giving me problems to make it work. Actually it is allowing any character:

```
def clean_fullname_arabic(self):
    fullname_arabic = self.cleaned_data['fullname_arabic']
    if not re.match(r'[\u0627-\u064a]+$', fullname_arabic):
        raise forms.ValidationError("Only Arabic chars")
```

I know the problem must be in my Regex, but I am confusing concepts here and can't make it work.

Comment: Shouldn't you be trying with `^[\u0627-\u064a]$` ? According to [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_script_in_Unicode) there are more characters you might want to include.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a couple of issues with that check line, first the Regex should be reversed like (you may want to add `_-`):

```
if re.findall(u'[^\u0627-\u064a\W]', fullname_arabic, flags=re.UNICODE)
```

also notice `r'` is replaced by `u'`, because `\u0628` won't be interpreted wi `r'`

Edit: From a previous project of mine, the Arabic range should be changed to `\u0621-\u06ED`