# Remove symbols in dataset

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I applied all preprocessing step, but I want to delete the rows that have English words or specific symbols, just i want words in the Arabic language without these symbols or English words that I mention it in below code.
I applied the code, but when I print the dataset after cleaning, it still without cleaning! i want to remove it not replace it.

```
lexicon = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\User\Python Code\data.csv")
lexicon.head(10)

#output
    Vocabulary
0   [PAD]
1   [UNK]
2   [CLS]
3   [SEP]
4   [MASK]
5   !
6   #
7   $
8   %
9   &

lexicon['clean_tweet'] = lexicon.Vocabulary.str.replace('[^\w\s#@/:%.,_-]', '', flags=re.UNICODE) #removes emojis
lexicon['clean_tweet'] = lexicon.clean_tweet.str.replace('@[_A-Za-z0-9]+', '') #removes handles
lexicon['clean_tweet'] = lexicon.clean_tweet.str.replace('[A-Za-z0-9]+', '') #removes english
lexicon['clean_tweet'] = lexicon.clean_tweet.str.replace('#',' ') #removes hashtag symbol only
lexicon['clean_tweet'] = lexicon.clean_tweet.str.replace(r'http\S+', '', regex=True).replace(r'www\S+', '', regex=True) #removes links
lexicon['clean_tweet'] = lexicon.clean_tweet.str.replace('\d+', '') #removes numbers
lexicon['clean_tweet'] = lexicon.clean_tweet.str.replace('\n', ' ') #removes new line
lexicon['clean_tweet'] = lexicon.clean_tweet.str.replace('_', '') #removes underscore
lexicon['clean_tweet'] = lexicon.clean_tweet.str.replace('[^\w\s]','') #removes punctuation
lexicon.head(10)

# Vocabulary    clean_tweet
0   [PAD]   
1   [UNK]   
2   [CLS]   
3   [SEP]   
4   [MASK]  
5   !   
6   #   
7   $   
8   %   
9   &
```

I want to remove all rows that contain these symbols or any language, just I need arabic word,
or is there another simple way to detect the Arabic words only?

**note: if the row contains Arabic words and symbols, just I want to delete symbols without Arabic words.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going by [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27685984/using-range-in-regex-for-arabic-letters), a Unicode regex range for Arabic letters is:

```
[\u0627-\u064a]
```

We can try using the negative version of this character class along with `str.replace`:

```py
lexicon['clean_tweet'] = lexicon.clean_tweet.str.replace(r'[^\u0627-\u064a]', '')
```

If you want to spare whitespace characters or other punctuation symbols, then you could try using this regex:

```regex
[^\u0627-\u064a\s!?.-]
```

Comment: thnx, when applied the first scripts it is run correctly, but the second scripts to save the symbols with words does not apply!?

Comment: It would help me if you could add some examples of the various types of replacements you want to do here.  I think my answer can be workable for you, but I need more information.

Comment: I have a lexicon that contains many languages "words" (English, Spanish, Indian) and many symbols, just I need the Arabic words without any other language and any symbols.

Comment: My current regex should only retain Arabic letters, not whitespace, not symbols.