# what is regexp for persian character in java?

Tags: java, regex

In the pattern `@Pattern(regexp = "^[a-zA-Z \b]+$")`, if I want to accept Persian characters, what should be added? I want both English and Persian characters to be valid with no digits.

Comment: What have you tried ? Are you looking for someone to just do it for you ? follow this [link](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) and come back with what you have tried.

Comment: Might want to convert to raw unicode and find the range of characters you are looking for.

Comment: Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22565100/regex-for-accepting-only-persian-characters

Comment: your link is for Arabic or persian character,if i want accept both english and persian how change it? @Pattern(regexp = "^[\\u0600-\\u06FF\\uFB8A\\u067E\\u0686\\u06AF]+$")