# Add space between Persian numeric and letter with python re

Tags: python, regex, persian

I want to **add space between Persian number and Persian letter** like this:

**"سعید123" convert to "سعید 123"**

Java code of this procedure is like below.

```
str.replaceAll("(?<=\\p{IsDigit})(?=\\p{IsAlphabetic})", " ").
```

But I can't find any **python solution**.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I think python is more wiser than that :)

Comment: Well, if you want to insert the space between any Unicode letter and digit, use `re.sub(r'(?u)([^\W\d_])(\d)', r'\1 \2', s)`. Note that `(?u)` is only needed in Python 2.x. In Python 3.x, the patterns are Unicode-aware by default and you may remove it, `r'([^\W\d_])(\d)'`.

Comment: @SaeedBibak are you interested in a job in tehran?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a short regex which you may rely on to match boundary between letters and digits (in any language):

```
\d(?=[^_\d\W])|[^_\d\W](?=\d)
```

[**Live demo**](https://regex101.com/r/HtOQKM/1)

**Breakdown**:

- `\d` Match a digit
- `(?=[^_\d\W])` Preceding a letter from a language
- `|` Or
- `[^_\d\W]` Match a letter from a language
- `(?=\d)` Preceding a digit

Python:

```
re.sub(r'\d(?![_\d\W])|[^_\d\W](?!\D)', r'\g<0> ', str, flags = re.UNICODE)
```

But according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50018691/1020526), ***this is the right way*** to accomplish this task:

```
re.sub(r'\d(?=[آابپتثجچحخدذرزژسشصضطظعغفقکگلمنوهی])|[آابپتثجچحخدذرزژسشصضطظعغفقکگلمنوهی](?=\d)', r'\g<0> ', str,  flags = re.UNICODE)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is a correct approach.

```
import re
k = "سعید123"
m = re.search("(\d+)", k)
if m:
    k = " ".join([m.group(), k.replace(m.group(), "")])
    print(k)
```

**Output:**

```
123 سعید
```

Comment: It is work in only one number phrase. But what I want is something that works in the case like:
"4سعید5سعید"

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
re.sub(r'([^\W\d_])(\d)', r'\1 \2', s, flags=re.U)
```

Note that in Python 3.x, `re.U` flag is redundant as the patterns are Unicode aware by default.

See the [online Python demo](https://ideone.com/c6m43D) and a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/E7w3IF/1).

**Pattern details**

- `([^\W\d_])` - Capturing group 1: any Unicode letter (literally, any char other than a non-word, digit or underscore chars)
- `(\d)` - Capturing group 2: any Unicode digit

The replacement pattern is a combination of the Group 1 and 2 placeholders (referring to corresponding captured values) with a space in between them.

You may use a variation of the regex with a lookahead:

```
re.sub(r'[^\W\d_](?=\d)', r'\g<0> ', s)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/E7w3IF/2).