# Regex for accepting English and Persian text

Tags: asp.net

I am working on a form which one of its custom validators should only accept English and Persian text, I tried the following expression that includes English and Arabic characters only, Arabic doesn't include all Persian characters, any help

```
ValidationExpression="^[\u0600-\u065F\u066A-\u06EF\u06FA-\u06FFa-zA-Z]+[\u0600-\u065F\u066A-\u06EF\u06FA-\u06FFa-zA-Z-_]*$
```

Comment: This link might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22565100/regex-for-accepting-only-persian-characters

Comment: It works only for Persian characters I think