# Dart Regex does not match whole word for Arabic text

Tags: regex, dart

This pattern works fine in Java and javascript but does not seem to work in Dart. Any help is appreciated.

```
void main() {
        String englishText = "The new nature will not find rest";
        String englishFind = "Nature";  
        RegExp englishExp = new RegExp("\\b$englishFind\\b", unicode:true, caseSensitive:false);
        bool englishResult = englishExp.hasMatch(englishText);//matches
        print(englishResult); //true

        String arabicText = "لن تجد الطبيعة الجديدة راحتها";
        String arabicFind="الطبيعة";
        RegExp arabicExp = new RegExp("\\b$arabicFind\\b", unicode:true);
        bool arabicResult = arabicExp.hasMatch(arabicText);//does not match
        print(arabicResult);//false
    }
```

Comment: `\b` is only working for ASCII letters/digits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\b` word boundary is still matching only in ASCII only contexts even when you define [`unicode:true`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.2/dart-core/RegExp/isUnicode.html) whose main point is to make sure "*UTF-16 surrogate pairs in the original string will be treated as a single code point and will not match separately*".

You may "decompose" the word boundary and add [Arabic letter and digit ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29729405/3832970) to the class:

```
String arabicText = "لن تجد الطبيعة الجديدة راحتها";
String arabicFind="الطبيعة";
RegExp arabicExp = new RegExp("(?:^|[^a-zA-Z0-9_\\u06F0-\\u06F9\\u0622\\u0627\\u0628\\u067E\\u062A-\\u062C\\u0686\\u062D-\\u0632\\u0698\\u0633-\\u063A\\u0641\\u0642\\u06A9\\u06AF\\u0644-\\u0648\\u06CC\\u202C\\u064B\\u064C\\u064E-\\u0652])$arabicFind(?![a-zA-Z0-9_\\u06F0-\\u06F9\\u0622\\u0627\\u0628\\u067E\\u062A-\\u062C\\u0686\\u062D-\\u0632\\u0698\\u0633-\\u063A\\u0641\\u0642\\u06A9\\u06AF\\u0644-\\u0648\\u06CC\\u202C\\u064B\\u064C\\u064E-\\u0652])", unicode:true);
bool arabicResult = arabicExp.hasMatch(arabicText);//does not match
print(arabicResult); // => true
```

The regex will match an `$arabicFind` word when it is

- `(?:^|[^a-zA-Z0-9_\u06F0-\u06F9\u0622\u0627\u0628\u067E\u062A-\u062C\u0686\u062D-\u0632\u0698\u0633-\u063A\u0641\u0642\u06A9\u06AF\u0644-\u0648\u06CC\u202C\u064B\u064C\u064E-\u0652])` - preceded with start of string (`^`) or (`|`) any char but ASCII letter, digit or `_` and Farsi letters or digits
- `(?![a-zA-Z0-9_\u06F0-\u06F9\u0622\u0627\u0628\u067E\u062A-\u062C\u0686\u062D-\u0632\u0698\u0633-\u063A\u0641\u0642\u06A9\u06AF\u0644-\u0648\u06CC\u202C\u064B\u064C\u064E-\u0652])` - not followed with an ASCII letter, digit or `_` and Farsi letters or digits.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, really appreciate your quick response. Will try it out.

Comment: @nick I think it should be enough, in case you need to support more languages, let me know.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor! I do need to support Farsi as well.

Comment: @nick I updated the solution to work with Farsi based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50018691/3832970).

Comment: Thank you. I marked your answer above as "accepted". Any ideas if the dart team will be fixing this?

Comment: @nick I do not know, but even in JS latest ECMAScript 2018+ `\b` is still not Unicode aware (`/\bВиктор\b/.test("Виктор")` yields *`false`*). Dart team [seems to be aware](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/28404) of the Unicode regex challenges.

Comment: Wiktor, I have a regex method that removes diacritics form Arabic. I have a list of about 31102 records average length 250. In Flutter dev mode it takes about 800 milliseconds to process, in release mode it take about 10 seconds. I would expect release to process much faster not slower, any ideas why?.   String removeDiacritics(){
    return this.replaceAll(RegExp(r'\u{0640}|\u{064D}|\u{064C}|\u{064B}|\u{064E}|\u{064F}|\u{0650}|\u{0651}|\u{0652}', unicode:true), '')
          .replaceAll(RegExp(r'\u{0623}|\u{0625}', unicode:true),'\u{0627}');
  }

Comment: @nick Hi Nick, no idea why that happens, and I agree it is weird, unless there is something in between that hinders the code execution. Note that you should not use `(a|b|c|d)`, you should use `[abcd]`, that is, `r'[\u0640\u064D\u064C\u064B\u064E\u064F\u0650\u0651\u0652]'` and `r'[\u0623\u0625]'`.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, I really do appreciate all your comments and input. Will correct the code as you suggested. Btw I am using Flutter 1.18.0-11.1.pre • channel beta. I also noticed that Flutter 1.17 seemed to run faster in general.