# Regex: How to match words without Arabic vowels?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to solve this in regex, I have to remove any words with Arabic vowels which are [و ا ي], and need to add rules like when it's at the beginning of the word, don't match and when it's after this pattern [ال]  also don't match. How to apply these rules in regex?

This is a sample of my file

```
تفقدت نظارتي  حين استيقظت صباحا  فلم اجدها في مكانها  وبحثت عنها في كل مكان  دون ان اعثر لها علي اثر  يا الهي  كيف ساخرج اليوم من البيت  واواجه النهار  
 وتناهي الي من الخارج  صوت نقار الخشب  فوق جذع شجره قريبه فاسرعت الي الباب  وفتحته  واذا ضوء النهار يبهر بصري  فاغلقت عيني  وهتفت  ايها النقار  اين انت  
 وحاولت عبثا ان افتح عيني  وانا اقول  عفوا  لا استطيع ان افتح عيني  ان الضوء يعميني
```

This is my code so far,

```
result_novowels = re.findall(r'\b(?:(?![اوي]))+\b', text_norm, re.I)
print(result_novowels)
```

This is the output

```
['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
```

I'm not very experienced with regex and I've been unable to find anything about how to do this online, so it'd be awesome if someone with more experience could help me out. Thanks!

Comment: is regex a necissity? I think wihtout regex will be easier

Comment: Yes, it's a requirement

Comment: try using unicode like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22565100/regex-for-accepting-only-persian-characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**
The simple solution proposed by questioner is:

```
\b[^اويى\W]+\b
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bqww8B/1)

Apparently a general form of a Unicode character could capture other contextual form of it (at least for Arabic in Python).

It is not complete but you could add desired and non-desired Unicode to it.

```
\b((?:(?!(\u0627|\u064A|\u0648))(?:[\u0600-\u06FF]))+?)\b
```

So We first ensure the left boundary of the word to be either `\s` or start of the string `\A` and consume the `\s` if any exist. Then we capture set of Unicode characters `[\u0600-\u06FF]` as long as they don't belong to vowels `(?!(\u0627|\u064A|...))` until we reach the end of the word by looking at either `\s` or end of the string `$`.

add all vowels from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_script_in_Unicode)

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/HLM1Vi/1)

Comment: I tried this and it worked '\b[^اويى\W]+\b'

Comment: I tried your solution but the output is between parenthesis not list, but it worked and give me another number of non-vowel words, and I can't check them all