# How to find all persian words in Visual Studio Code

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I want to write a regular expression that find all persian words in my project. How can I do it?

Can i do it with Shift+Ctrl+F and Regex?

There are questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17315989/how-to-write-a-regular-expression-for-entering-persian-characters-only). But this not work in VSCode.
See image below for error:

[image: error parsing regex in vscode]

Comment: @rkta do yo see image?

Comment: My VSCode version is 1.22.2