# How to split str, that contains farsi and english words using re module on python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, arabic, farsi

I have some_str = 'دریافت اطلاعات در مورد HDD {hdd}'. I need regex for splitting this by farsi and non farsi words for getting result like this:
['دریافت اطلاعات در مورد', 'HDD {hdd}']

```
import re
some_str = 'دریافت اطلاعات در مورد HDD {hdd}'
regex = '???'
re.split(regex, some_str)
```

For another str like `"اضافه کردن اعلام کننده {notifier} روی سرور {host} بوسیله کاربر {role}/{user} از آدرس های IP {ip_address}"` i expect next result:

`['اضافه کردن اعلام کننده', '{notifier}', 'روی سرور', '{host}', 'بوسیله کاربر', '{role}/{user}', 'از آدرس های', 'IP {ip_address}']`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use this `re.split`:

```sh
import re
# regex for arabic text
reg = re.compile('([\u0600-\u06FF]+(?:\s+[\u0600-\u06FF]+)*)\s*')

# or for matching Persian characters only use:
# [\u0622\u0627\u0628\u067E\u062A-\u062C\u0686\u062D-\u0632\u0698\u0633-\u063A\u0641\u0642\u06A9\u06AF\u0644-\u0648\u06CC]

some_str = 'دریافت اطلاعات در مورد HDD {hdd}'
lst1 = list(filter(None, reg.split(some_str)))
print (lst1)
## ['دریافت اطلاعات در مورد', 'HDD {hdd}']

s = "اضافه کردن اعلام کننده {notifier} روی سرور {host} بوسیله کاربر {role}/{user} از آدرس های IP {ip_address}"
lstw = list(filter(None, reg.split(s)))
print (lst2)
## ['اضافه کردن اعلام کننده', '{notifier} ', 'روی سرور', '{host} ', 'بوسیله کاربر', '{role}/{user} ', 'از آدرس های', 'IP {ip_address}']
```

[`\[\u0600-\u06FF\]`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17524562/548225) is used to match Persian characters.

**RegEx Details:**

- `([\u0600-\u06FF]+(?:\s+[\u0600-\u06FF]+)*)`: Match space separated Persian text at the start in capture group #1
- `\s*`: Match 0 or more whitespaces
- `(.*)`: Match remainder of string in capture group #2

Comment: `[\u0600-\u06FF]` is an Arabic script pattern, [Farsi/Persian regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22565100/regex-for-accepting-only-persian-characters) is different.

Comment: For other str, like "اضافه کردن اعلام کننده {notifier} روی سرور {host} بوسیله کاربر {role}/{user} از آدرس های IP {ip_address}" this solution does not give the result that i expect. I expect this: ['اضافه کردن اعلام کننده', '{notifier}', 'روی سرور', '{host}', 'بوسیله کاربر', '{role}/{user}', 'از آدرس های', 'IP {ip_address}']

Comment: @MartinAkbaev: Please try my updated answer now