# How to detect if edittext has English characters

Tags: java, android

I want to detect if my `edittext` has English characters and notify user to change it because i want just Persian characters for name and family name. how can i filter `edittext` to accept just Persian characters or detect English characters and show an error?

Comment: Despite having different tags, this question is a possible duplicate of [Regex for check the input string is just in persian language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10561590/regex-for-check-the-input-string-is-just-in-persian-language) - since the only relevant part is the regular expression involved.

Comment: @Amir_P Can you paste your code pls?

Comment: check in edit text  have string A-z and a-z with help of Regx strings on textchangelistner

Comment: You can achieve this Using `Text Watcher`.

Comment: Also, don't check for the existence of English characters - check for the existence of any non-Persian character. 'ñ' is neither English nor Persian, for example.

Comment: refer https://detectlanguage.com/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think its not easy to detect and inform user to instruct.
Simply u can do something like this.
In XML file:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/LanguageText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:digits="@string/app_lan" />
```

In Strings.xml :

```
<string name="app_lan">YOUR LANGUAGE</string>
```

Example If English :

```
<string name="app_lan">abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</string>
```

For ur language same like this.

Answer (score 4):

Persian characters are within the range: `[\u0600-\u06FF]`. Validate your string with regex.

Answer (score 4):

Try the following regular expression **Persian** characters range.

```
public static final Pattern RTL_CHARACTERS = 
    Pattern.compile("[\u0600-\u06FF\u0750-\u077F\u0590-\u05FF\uFE70-\uFEFF]");
Matcher matcher = RTL_CHARACTERS.matcher("Texts");
if(matcher.find()){
   return true;  // it's RTL
}
```

**Or Use this method.**

```
public static boolean textPersian(String s) {
for (int i = 0; i < Character.codePointCount(s, 0, s.length()); i++) {
    int c = s.codePointAt(i);
    if (c >= 0x0600 && c <=0x06FF || c== 0xFB8A || c==0x067E || c==0x0686 || c==0x06AF)
        return true;
}
return false;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public final static String PERSIAN_STRING = "ا آ ب پ ت ث ج چ ح خ د ذ ر ز ژ س ش ص ض ط ظ ع غ ف ق ک گ ل م ن و ه ی";
public final static String LATIN_STRING = "a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z";

 if (PERSIAN_STRING.contains(str.toLowerCase()))
     lang = "PERSIAN";

  if (LATIN_STRING.contains(str.toLowerCase()))
      lang = "LATIN";
```

Comment: What if the text contains these: áéíóúçñ¢£

Comment: @Renan and are they valid English characters?

Comment: They are. English has words like "resumé", "fiancé" etc.

Answer (score 1):

Summarizing a couple things here. Since, [@Sergei Podlipaev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5257935/sergei-podlipaev) has noted that Persian characters are in the range `\u0600` to `\u06FF`, you can use regex. I am not sure if I am specifying the bounds correctly, but this will give you an idea.

To see if english character set is used - `^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$` 
To see if Persian character set is used - `^[\u0600-\u06FF]+$`