# How can I detect letters in other languages (not English) in the string?

Tags: php, regex

Here is my code:

```
function isValid($string) {
    return strlen($string) >= 6 &&
           strlen($string) <= 40 &&
           preg_match("/\d/", $string) &&
           preg_match("/[a-zA-Z]/", $string);
}

// Negative test cases
assert(!isValid("hello"));

// Positive test cases
assert(isValid("abcde2"));
```

As you see, my script validates a string based on 4 conditions. Now I'm trying to develop this one:

```
preg_match("/[a-zA-Z]/", $string)
```

This condition returns `true` just for English letters. How can I also add other letters like `ا ب ث چ`. Well how can I do that?

**Note:** Those characters aren't Arabic, they are Persian.

Comment: Use `preg_match('/\p{L}/u', $string)` and replace `strlen` with `mb_strlen`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Ah ok, just may you please tell me what's the meaning of `\p` and `{l}`?

Comment: `\p{L}` matches any Unicode character. It does not match diacritics though. Perhaps, you need `preg_match('/\p{L}\p{M}*+/u', $string)`. Please check if that works for you.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Well actually I don't need to match diacritics characters. All I'm trying to do is: checking whether is the string containing a letter or not? *(that letter can be a English letter or Persian letter)*

Comment: Ah, ok, Persian and English? `preg_match('/[\x{0600}-\x{06FF}A-Z]/iu', $string)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Either Persian or English or even both of them. Anyway I need to see a letter to validate that string. Btw why you don't write an answer?

Comment: I need to know what you need before answering :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match either an English or Persian letter, you may use

```
preg_match('/[\x{0600}-\x{06FF}A-Z]/iu', $string)
```

The `\x{0600}-\x{06FF}` range is [supposed to match all Persian letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10561590/regex-for-check-the-input-string-is-just-in-persian-language). The `A-Z` range will match all ASCII letters (both upper- ans lowercase since the `/i` case insensitive modifier is used). The `/u` modifier is necessary since you are working with Unicode characters.

Also, use `mb_strlen` rather than `strlen` when checking a Unicode string length, it will count the Unicode code points correctly.

As for

> *Your password should be containing at least a letter (that letter can be in any language*

You need to use

```
preg_match('/\p{L}/u', $string)
```

or

```
preg_match('/\p{L}\p{M}*+/u', $string)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

that will match any letter (even the one with a diacritic after it). `\p{L}` matches any base Unicode letter, and `\p{M}*+` will possessively match 0+ diacritics after it. If the match value is not used, `/\p{L}/u` will suffice for the check.

Comment: Great .. upvote. Just as a note, that string is a password, and I have this rule to validate the password: *"your password should be containing at least a letter (that letter can be in any language, like EN, or FA or ..)"*. So do you think your pattern still is fine?

Comment: You are redefining requirements on the fly, you know? It is not a good thing.