# how to validate Persian Slug in laravel?

Tags: regex, laravel, slug, farsi

My project need to validate slug and Laravel does not handle Persian slug validator.So I have to use Regex.My slugs are like These:

```
/sony-صوتی-و-تصویری-15
/لباس-خوشگل-مجلسی
/songs-birds-15
```

I not found regex for pass this slugs.
Do you have a solution?

Comment: What type of validation are you looking for?

Comment: i meant ValidatesRequests but I just want a regex to match the above slugs.like this https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#rule-regex

Comment: Those are very different slugs - it's difficult to help you without seeing some code

Comment: Does this answer help you? https://stackoverflow.com/q/10561590

Comment: Do you want your slug is like `product-id-value`?

Comment: each product have  slug and It is entered by the user as desired.

Answer (score 0):

In this example, it only accepts Persian letters
An error is displayed if there are English letters

```
 $validate = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'name' => 'required|regex:/^[\x{پچجحخهعغفقثصضشسیبلاتنمکگوئدذرزطظژؤإأءًٌٍَُِّ }]*$/u',

        ],
            [
                'name.regex' => 'نام باید به فارسی وارد شود',
            ]);
        if ($validate->fails()) {
            return [
                "status" => false,
                "error" => ['message' => $validate->errors()->messages()]
            ];
        }
```