# How to detect Persian characters in string

Tags: c#

I've got a string value with a lot of different characters and I want to get a string contains with permitted characters.
For Example: I've got this string **"geeks01$سهیلاطریقی03.02geeks!@!!."** but I want to return this value:**"0103.سهیلاطریقی02@."**
The following `Class` is for detecting valid characters. and it works correctly .but I can't find an `expression`for **persian** characters.
Does anyone have any idea for fixing this problem? or any solution for better performance because I care about bottleneck and it must run about 8,000,000 times :)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            string str = "geeks01$سهیلاطریقی03.02geeks!@!!.";
            splitString(str, true, false, true, new char[] { '@', '.' });
        }
        static string splitString(string str, bool keepNumber, bool keepEnglishAlpha, bool keepPersianbAlpha, char[] special)
        {
            StringBuilder value =
                     new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
            {
                if (Char.IsDigit(str[i]) && keepNumber == true)
                    value.Append(str[i]);

                if (keepEnglishAlpha == true)
                    if ((str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'Z') || (str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z'))
                        value.Append(str[i]);

                if (keepPersianbAlpha == true)
                {
                    //todo
                }
                if (special.Length >= 1)
                {
                    foreach (var specialChar in special)
                    {
                        if (str[i] == specialChar)
                            value.Append(str[i]);
                    }
                }

            }
            return value.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10561590/regex-for-check-the-input-string-is-just-in-persian-language

Comment: Thank you but I want to use c# not Java Script. @i486

Comment: This regex has error in `\s` @viveknuna **Error CS1009 Unrecognized escape sequence**

Comment: @SoheilaTarighi try this `Regex.IsMatch(Text, @"^[\u0600-\u06ff\s]+$|[\u0750-\u077f\s]+$|[\ufb50-\ufc3f\s]+$|[\ufe70-\ufefc\s]+$|[\u06cc\s]+$|[\u067e\s]+$|[\u06af\s]$|[\u0691\s]+$|^$");`

Comment: could you share some other examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Enumerable.Aggregate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate?view=netcore-3.1) method to improve the function and return the desired output based on the specified conditions.

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Globalization;
//...

//Suggested rename...
static string FilterString(
    string str, 
    bool keepNumber, 
    bool keepEnglishAlpha, 
    bool keepPersianbAlpha, 
    char[] special
    ) =>
    str.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (sb, c) =>
        (keepNumber && char.IsDigit(c))
        || (keepEnglishAlpha && ((c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') || (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')))
        || (keepPersianbAlpha && char.GetUnicodeCategory(c) == UnicodeCategory.OtherLetter)
        || (special != null && special.Contains(c))
        ? sb.Append(c) : sb.Append(string.Empty)).ToString();
```

- [Char.IsDigit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.isdigit?view=netcore-3.1) method to recognize the digits.
- Append the Latin characters if the `keepEnglishAlpha` is `true`.
- [Char.GetUnicodeCategory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.getunicodecategory?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Char.GetUnicodeCategory);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7.2);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netcore-3.1) method which returns [UnicodeCategory.OtherLetter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.unicodecategory?view=netcore-3.1) for the Persian characters.
- Append the special characters if the `special` array contains them.

Testing the mentioned above string:

```cs
public static void Main()
{
    var input = "geeks01$سهیلاطریقی03.02geeks!@!!.";
    var output = FilterString(input, true, false, true, new[] { '@', '.' });

    Console.WriteLine(output);
}
```

Writes:

```
01سهيلاطريقي03.02@.
```

Comment: Than you ,your solution works correctly, How I can replace ی ک arabic with ی ک persian ?
@JQSOFT

Comment: @SoheilaTarighi Most welcome Ma`am. Could you please give me a string with these characters to check it out?

Comment: For Example :`علي` Convert To `علی` and `شکاك` convert to `شکاک` how to detect arabic `ي ك`  from input variable and convert to  persian `ی ک` 
For Example : **"geeks01$سهيلاطريقي03.02geeks!@!!.";**  and I want to return **01سهیلاطریقی03.02@.** remove arabic `ي`  and replace with  persian`ی`

Comment: @SoheilaTarighi Use: `var s = "شکاك".Replace("\u0643", "\u06A9");` and `var s = "علي".Replace("\u064A", "\u0649");`. Check the links out for more: [Arabic Alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_script_in_Unicode) and [Persian Alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persian_alphabet).